# JQuery Autocomplete Form from Database fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm following a tutorial (http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step) and I try to do this but with a local phpmyadmin database, using Xampp installed on my PC.

I have a table called **cars** with the columns **id** and **name**, I filled in 2 entries, however, the autocomplete doesn't work, in fact, I don't get any suggestions below my form. Since I can't bother you with all the JS files, maybe someone can explain what this precisely does, especially the last **while** function, because I think here lies the problem:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM cars';
for($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
  $sql .= ' AND name LIKE ' . "'%" . $conn->real_escape_string($parts[$i]) . "%'";
}


while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
  $a_json_row["id"] = $row['id'];
  $a_json_row["value"] = $row['name'];
  $a_json_row["label"] = $row['name'];
  array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring `WHERE` in your SQL statement.  Query likely failing, yielding zero autocomplete options.

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM cars';
for($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
  if ($i == 0){ $sql.= " WHERE"; } // THIS LINE HERE
  $sql .= ' AND name LIKE ' . "'%" . $conn->real_escape_string($parts[$i]) . "%'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it unfortunately. The textbox blinks for a short moment when I type something in, but still no suggestions appear.

Comment: I solved it by using a different approach. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Should probably post your solution and mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

My Solution to this Problem:

```
while($cars=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=>$cars["name"],
                    'label'=>$cars["name"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);
```